# How to stop Safari MutationObserver from batching results without using a timer?

Tags: javascript, safari, contenteditable, mutation-observers

It seems that using `MutationObserver` for `contenteditable` in Safari will cause some problems. Safari would not notify my script unless some scripts are about to execute. Consider the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p contenteditable id="target"></p>
    <div id="log"></div>
    <script>
      log = document.getElementById('log');
      function print (text) {
        log.innerText = text + '\n' + log.innerText;
      }
      var fnCallback = function (mutations) {
          mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
              print(mutation.type);
              if (mutation.type == 'characterData') {
                print(mutation.oldValue);
                print(document.getElementById('target').innerText);
              }
              window.keeper = mutation;
          });
      };

      document.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
        console.log('keyup');
      });
      function refresh () {
        setTimeout(function () {
          refresh();
        }, 100);
      }
      refresh();

      var observer = new MutationObserver(fnCallback),
          elTarget = document.querySelector("#target"),
          objConfig = {
              childList: true,
              subtree : true,
              characterData : true,
              characterDataOldValue : true
          };

      observer.observe(elTarget, objConfig);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

One can try to remove the `keyup` event listener as well as the `refresh` function. On my latest Safari on latest released El Capitan, nothing will be printed to `#log` unless I open the Web Inspector, which forces Safari to evaluate. Adding `keyup` event listener seems to resolve the issue at first, but there exist ways to input without using a keyboard, including but not limited to spelling correction and Chinese handwriting input using a Trackpad. A timer, though practically acceptable—with `requestAnimationFrame` particularly—seems not very elegant.

I am wondering is there any other way to resolve this issue, or to turn off this lazy evaluation feature altogether?